# AWS IOT Certificates not found from Terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, esp8266, aws-iot, nodemcu

I created a AWS IOT, created Certificate and policy too for interacting from Node MCU/ ESP8266
ESP is well connected with WiFi but not with AWS IOT, returning MQTT error code -2
Meanwhile, i try to list Certificate that i created but not showing on terminal

`aws iot describe-certificate --certificate-id "**********************************"

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeCertificate operation: CertificateId ************************************** does not exist`

```
aws iot describe-certificate --certificate-id "**********************************"

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeCertificate operation: CertificateId ************************************** does not exist

aws iot list-certificates

{
    "certificates": []
}
```

But i can clearly view those certificates navigating through, AWS IoT>Security>Certificates

Tried with same region and different region,
Tried with SSO and IAM USER

I guess that my mqtt is not connected due to this reason, i expect to connect with AWS IOT

Comment: are you sure your aws cli is configured with the right account and region?

Comment: Thanks   

aws iot list-certificates --region us_***_1

Works  But  MQTT is not still connected.